# What Is the CLI Command To Deploy a Release Build to a Physical iOS Device on a Mac

Tags: maui

I've had almost complete failure trying to deploy my MAUI app to a physical device using Visual Studio for Mac.  It's like a different error almost every time.  So I've resorted to trying to deploy it to my plugged in iPhone using the CLI.  I originally started with a command like this:

```
dotnet build -t:Run -p:_DeviceName=00008101-blahblahblah
```

It kept throwing errors about not being able to find an emulator with that device ID.  So I first did a debug build and deploy using Visual Studio to the device, then I changed my CLI command to this:

```
dotnet build -t:Run -f:net6.0-ios -c:Release 
-p:_DeviceName=00008101-blahblahblah
```

This also fails with multiple errors, like

- 'can't find publishing profile'
- 'AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: 0xe8008015'
- 'The command "/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/15.4.447/tools/bin/mlaunch --installdev bin/Release/net6.0-ios/ios-arm64/WatchLikesApp.app/ --devname 00008101-blahblahblah" exited with code 1.

I've been trying to get this to work for like three days.  Is there some straightforward way to get this deployed to my locally attached physical iOS device on my Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Based on the error `AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: 0xe8008015`, it looks like your device is not in the provisioning profiles that you currently have, please refer to [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6591#issuecomment-1112076560) for more details.

**2.** If you want to run the app, you can execute the Run target by adding /t:Run to the command line. Please use the command below to deploy the app to your local iPhone. For more details, you can refer to [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6395#issuecomment-1109835413).

```
$ dotnet build /t:Run /p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64 -f net6.0-ios myProject.csproj
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandar, unfortunately that did not work either.  I also looked at the thread you mentioned to add the device ID to the command line, but that did not help either.  So here is the command line I used:dotnet build -t:Run -p:RuntimeIddentifier=ios-arm64 -f net6.0-ios -p:_DeviceName=00008101-blahblahblah watchlikesapp.csproj            Here's as much of the error as will fit in the comments window: 
 EXEC : error MT1212: Failed to create a simulator where type = iPhone 4s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s) and runtime = iOS 15.5 (15.5 - 19F70) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.S

Comment: What is your iPhone type? It looks like this deploy only supports `arm64`.

Comment: It's an iPhone 12 with iOS 15.6.  Ironically after trying all of these different CLI combinations, the Visual Studio deployment started working on it so I'm using that now for as long as it will continue working.

Comment: Sure, if it helps others as is I don't have a problem accepting it, I just haven't found anything to add to it that gets it to the finish line for me so I can't really add to it.